# Стоит ли void метод отмечать как статический?

Tags: java, ооп

Стоит ли в Java `void` методы помечать как `static`, если объекты в данном проекте используются для хранения определенного состояния между вызовами метода, которое в свою очередь определяется возвращаемым значением?

Comment: Ага, прямо неправ был про синглтон. Прочитайте, пожалуйста, комментарии под ответом.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вся статика, как вы наверняка знаете, относится к классу, а не к конкретному экземпляру. С моей точки зрения, методы могут/должны быть статичными, когда они не привязаны к состоянию (например, создание выдержки из текста не предусматривает сохранение каких-либо значений, только анализ входных данных и возврат новых), а свойства - когда они не относятся к состоянию, а нужны для хранения каких-либо относительно постоянных вещей, не относящихся к состоянию (например, логгера).

Исходите из семантики, а не из требований сложившейся архитектуры.

Comment: Именно так. Семантика — главное.

Answer (score 1):

void или нет - вообще не имеет значения.

Если хранимое состояние единственно - используйте для хранения **объект-синглтон и вызывайте методы на нем**. Использовать при этом статические методы, которые будут внутренне обращаться к синглтону теоретически возможно, но **делать так не нужно**.

Если возможных носителей состояния много - **создавайте экземпляры, храните состояние в каждом и на нем же вызывайте методы**. Пример - класс [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

**static** нужно использовать **только в случае, если состояния нет** и экземпляр ни по каким иным причинам не нужен.

Comment: Нет. У класса нет состояния вообще. Превращать инстансы-одиночки в статику или синглтоны - это зло.

Comment: @Etki а чем инстанс-одиночка отличается от синглтона, если только он один нужен для хранения состояния?

Comment: Его нельзя будет продублировать, что рано или поздно аукнется; любой участок кода может его отмодифицировать незаметно для других. Синглтон, по факту - это скрытая глобальная переменная. Тестирование опять же уже не тестирование, и каждое лишнее обращение к статике хардкодит конкретный класс.

Comment: @Etki а если строго необходимо, чтобы все работали с единственным состоянием, как это правильно реализовать тогда? Например, логгер с общими настройками, вызываемый из разных классов. Или контейнер для потока рабочего какого-нибудь. Даже в этом случае просто совместно использовать один объект, но не делать его синглтоном?

Comment: Инжектить инстанс в конструктор / сеттер с помощью DI-контейнера.

Comment: @Etki хм, не сталкивался пока что с таким, пойду почитаю. Спасибо за объяснение.  Да, и раз уж ответ мой вдруг приняли - не могли бы вы отредактировать, чтобы там верные рекоммендации были?

Comment: Про DI-контейнер есть например тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/131993/

Comment: Неа. На самом деле все эти правила должны безоговорочно исполняться в крупных проектах, уж на что Yii все нарушал, а все его все равно любили :3